# When shrinking the page, the table above remains constant, mobile compatibility is not possible. How do I fix this problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

When shrinking the page, the table above remains constant, mobile compatibility is not possible. How do I fix this problem?
I tried it from different sources to be responsive, but the table on the top does not even move. If you help me, you will make me happy.

[image]

Comment: there are a few ways to fix this issue, how you want to approach it is really up to you: https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/ . Though, looking at the data, squishing does not look promising, so you can either do a scroll or collapse

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: [codes](https://codepen.io/bilal-inal/pen/YzNOPgR)

Comment: Could you create [an asp.net example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc)?

Comment: style="overflow-x:auto;"

Comment: [asp.net](https://codepen.io/bilal-inal/pen/PoWdjWj)

Comment: @Jennift that didn't work

Comment: i wrapped another div outside your fieldset and put the overflow class on it. The fieldset seems to be putting up some resistance. If you remove the fieldset tag, you can add the overflow code in the div right above the table. https://codepen.io/jennift/pen/vYgzZvZ?editors=1100

Comment: @Jennift yes that worked. Well, the table below shrinks the page when the page shrinks, but the upper one remains constant. What is the problem?

Comment: because of the length of info in first table. If you stretch your browser as wide as it can go, you will see that your first table stretches/shrinks too.

Comment: so there is no solution to this

Comment: you could do collapsible but it's a whole lot more codes: https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM